# Add custom styling to ion-select

Tags: css, ionic2

I have a ion-select with few options i gave a header using [selectOptions], is there a way to define a css so that i could able to set background-color to header, button alignment ,and add a icon to the header

```
 <ion-select [selectOptions]="daysOptions" #selectDays="ngModel" required name="selectedDay" [(ngModel)]="selectDay" >
         <ion-option *ngFor="let day of Days;" [value]="day.val">{{day.name}}</ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```

could someone help me

Comment: You mean the alert itself? [selectOptions] has an option called cssClass that will let you pass a class on to the alert. If you want to make your own custom component its really not that hard, here is an example for a select without ok/cancel: https://github.com/misha130/ionic2-select-nobuttons/blob/master/src/pages/select/selectalertless.ts

Answer (score 7):

**You can fix this easily now**

Add to ion-select element:

```
[interfaceOptions]="{cssClass: 'my-class'}"
```

Add to css:

```
.my-class .alert-wrapper {
    max-width: 94% !important;
}
```

Comment: <ion-select 
                    [interfaceOptions]="{cssClass: 'my-custom-alert-class'}"
.....
be sure to put the custum css into the global files.
.my-custom-alert-class .alert-wrapper {

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use cssClass in option like this:

```
// In your component
daysOptions = {
    cssClass: 'my-class',
    ...,
}
```

Then in css you can do what you want eg:

```
.my-class .alert-wrapper {
    max-width: 94% !important;
}
```

Thank's to ionic docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#advanced

Comment: This does not work..I mean passing cssClass option does not work for the popover interface

Answer (score 1):

I needed a color selector couple of months ago but I couldn’t find any. 
The only way to do this was using custom CSS. I tried adding CSS classes to ion-select and ion-option but the classes doesn’t get reflected in the generated output. So the only way to apply the custom CSS to ion-select and ion-options is by using the parent element and some JS.

You can check the logic in:
HTML:
https://github.com/ketanyekale/ionic-color-and-image-selector/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.html

TS:
https://github.com/ketanyekale/ionic-color-and-image-selector/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts

SCSS:
https://github.com/ketanyekale/ionic-color-and-image-selector/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.scss