# Ionic select option text cutting off

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic select list setup like below.  Why is the text not taking the full width of the select?

ionic -v --> 6.18.1

I've tried some suggestions from here but no luck: [Add custom styling to ion-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505873/add-custom-styling-to-ion-select)

```
.myCustomSelect{
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

<ion-select
    cssClass="myCustomSelect"
    [interface]="prmInterfaceType" 
    [multiple]="prmMultiSelect" 
    (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" 
    name="select-dropdown"
    ngDefaultControl>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let entity of prmEntities$ | async" [value]="entity">
        {{entity.entityName}}
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: did you put the css in the global file?

Comment: No I put it in the css file for my component.  Does it need to be in the global file?

Comment: yes, there's a difference between global & component file.

Comment: That did not change anything. I simply added this: 
`.myCustomSelect{
    max-width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: You need to set dynamic alert width

Comment: // set this in global.scss file `.setMaxHeight {
        --min-width: calc(100% - 30px);

        .alert-radio-label {
            white-space: nowrap !important;
            overflow: auto !important;
            text-overflow: unset;
        }
    }`

`<ion-select [interfaceOptions]="{cssClass: 'setMaxHeight'}"></ion-select>`